# Static Library ios : File not found error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, static-libraries

I am creating a static library for my project. Is all the classes created inside static library has to copy files in build phases? I have added only some of the files in build phase ->copy files. Now i am using this static library in my project. I got file not found error in static class file.

For Example:

Static Library - > It has 2 Classes.
1. One.h One.m
2. Two.h Two.m

In Two.h header file it has `#import "One.h"`

In build phase-> Copy files added only Two.h(As i don't want to show One.h to everyone)

MYProject - >
I am using Static library in this project.
I have added StaticLibrary.a file and the header paths.
Now i imported Two.h in my Project.
`#import <StaticLibrary/Two.h>`

Error:Cannot find the class One.h -> Inside Two.h

Could anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have a static library, if you don't have the "One.h" file then the other headers can't have it as an import.

Sorry, but you'll have to show One.h to everyone, or else rearrange your code. What is it that you don't want to expose? Does it have to go into a header file?

Comment: -I have some 50 classes in my static library. So i thought to give only  1 entry point class and not all the other classes to developers. So what is the better approach i can use at this point?